# Let's part ways with [computer-parts]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[computer-parts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-parts) appears to be a useless meta tag. Nobody is an expert on all computer parts and there is no reason to search for questions using that tag that I can think of.

Should we remove this tag?

---

Community concensus was yes and this tag has been removed.

Comment: I'm an expert at *disassembling* computer parts. Does that count?

Comment: @Twisty lol. There is always one troublemaker :)

Comment: What if the question is "what do you do with old computer parts"?

Comment: @Mehrdad Such a question would be off-topic as "opinion based" :)

Comment: Er, not "what do you do with" in that sense. I meant like if the goal was to find out if you should recycle them somehow or just throw them in the trash or find a disposal facility of some sort or whatever. You get my point...

Comment: @Mehrdad That's still opinion based, because it is based on local laws. In some places, for example NL, you have to take them to a special recycling point.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Sigh, that's not my point. **You get my point**. Can you stop dodging it? I'm trying to make a helpful comment and point something out and and move on, I don't have time for jokes or trolling.

Comment: @Mehrdad No I don't get your point. Please can add an answer explaining why you think we should keep this tag. So far you haven't convinced me of anything.

Comment: The point is **not every question about computer parts is about 1 specific computer part**. End of story.

Comment: @Mehrdad so?... That doesn't make the tag any more useful.

Comment: No more [tag:computer-parts] tags.

Answer (score 17):

Considering that Super User has a seperate tag for nearly all computer parts, ([ram](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ram), [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu), [power-supply](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-supply), [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive), [motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/motherboard), [graphics-card](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card) just to name some), I think this tag can safely be removed.

Comment: As of today that's 66 questions to edit, and likely to grow until it gets cleaned up. A tag wiki edit to say _Don't use this_ with references to the available parts tags would help. Seems like something to be added to a cleanup weekend, the next time we do one.